# Check if an array of objects contains another object

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
const arr = [
{name:"Bill", age:11},
{name:"Bill", age:11}
]
console.log(arr.includes({name:"Bill", age:11}))
```

Here i want to check if the array includes `{name:"Bill", age:11}`.
Why i get false? And how to make this checking using includes?

Comment: you compare an object with other objects. they have all different object references.

Comment: It can help [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: @NinaScholz, what could be the solution? Could you show please?

Comment: There is no built-in way to check equality on objects, because the comparison is done by reference (two objects can have different references even if they have the same contents). I suggest you either do the comparison key by key, or use a library method like [`_.isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual).

Comment: `arr.some(v => JSON.stringify(v) === JSON.stringify({name: "Bill", age: "11"}));`

Answer (score 8):

The `includes()` method compares objects by reference and not by value. In your case the three objects have three different references although they have the same properties and the same values in them.

```js
const bill = { name: 'Bill', age: 11 }
const arr = [bill, { name: 'Jane', age: 18 }]

arr.includes(bill) // true (same reference)
arr.includes({ name: 'Bill', age: 11 }) // false (different reference)
```

If you want to find objects by value, you can use the `find()` method and pass a filter function which checks if each property of the object matches your criteria.

```js
const arr = [{name:"Bill", age:11}, {name:"Jane", age:18}]
const exists = Boolean(arr.find(x => x.name === 'Bill' && x.age === 11))

// or even simpler using the `some()` method
const exists = arr.some(x => x.name === 'Bill' && x.age === 11)
```

Comment: An alternative to combining `Boolean()` and `Array.find()` is simply using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this method. I've added it to the examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom array prototype method for this like `includesObj`

```js
const arr = [
{name:"Bill", age:11},
{name:"Bill", age:11}
]

Array.prototype.includesObj = function(obj) {
   for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if(JSON.stringify(this[i], Object.keys(this[i]).sort()) === JSON.stringify(obj, Object.keys(obj).sort())) return true;
   }
   return false;
}

console.log(arr.includesObj({name: "Bill", age: 11}))
console.log(arr.includesObj({age: 11, name: "Bill"}))
console.log(arr.includesObj({name: "Bob", age: 11}))
```

Comment: if you want to have it relieable, you also need to add `Object.keys(this[i]).sort()` and `Object.keys(obj).sort()` as second parameter of `stringify`

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz sure? i get twice `true` at console log

Comment: but it would fail on `console.log(arr.includesObj({age: 11, name: "Bill"}))` if you don't do that

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz it was a typo by myself, it works